# Is it possible to find the row using something other than the primaryKey on SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to be able to find the value using either network_id or username.
Yet the following sintax gives the error of more than one primary key (as expected).

```
CREATE TABLE Player(
    network_id TEXT not null,
    username varchar2(50) not null,
    value INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT player_pk1 PRIMARY KEY (username),
    CONSTRAINT player_pk2 PRIMARY KEY (network_id)

);
```

Is there a way that I could do this in Sqlite?

Comment: table can have only one primary key

Comment: @Sergey, I am aware, I was just wondering how I could accomplish something similar within the bounds of Sql

Comment: sorry, but " to find the value using either network_id or username" is unrelated to primary key.

Comment: You don't need a key at all. With `select * from player where network_id = 123` you find rows via network ID and with `select * from player where username = 'Mr. X'` you find rows via username. You can provide indexes that speed up such queries. SQLite provides such indexes automatically on primary keys and columns with a unique constraint, but you can also create them yourself.

Comment: Is the network_id supposed to be unique in your table (i.e. is this actually a player ID) or can multiple players have the same network ID?

Answer (score 1):

A primary key has three components to its definition:

- `NOT NULL`
- `UNIQUE`
- Only one per table

That is why you cannot have more than one.  But you can have any number of `NOT NULL` `UNIQUE` columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Player(
    network_id TEXT not null,
    username varchar2(50) not null,
    value INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT player_pk1 PRIMARY KEY (username),
    CONSTRAINT unq_player_network_id UNIQUE (network_id)
);
```